# Check where a constant is #included from in a large C project

Tags: c, gcc

I have a project in C that I need to modify and run. At some point, in a source file I have

```
#ifndef THE_FLAG
// declare important stuff
#endif
```

but, I don't know where `THE_FLAG` is `#include`d from. It is *not* defined in my project, and it is hidden somewhere in external library.

I tried `gcc -M` but it shows the headers, without information if it was included directly or somewhere higher in the include hierarchy.

The project is too complicated to track all the dependencies by hand. It is build with `./configure && make`.

**Question:** how to track this external dependency?

Comment: Is it really THE_FLAG, or did you just use that as an example? If the name is sufficiently unique-sounding, I'd just grep all header files on the system for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try compiling with `gcc -E`.  This will tell gcc to stop at the preprocessing stage.  As part of that, it will tell you where all the `#define`s came from.

Note that this will create a text file, not a `.o` file.

Answer (score 2):

You can get gcc to tell you exactly where the flag is defined by redefining it for test purposes, e.g.

```
#include <limits.h>

#define INT_MAX 42

int f(void)
{
        return INT_MAX;
}
```

will make gcc complain

```
main.c:4:0: warning: "INT_MAX" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define INT_MAX 42
 ^
In file included from main.c:2:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.1/include/limits.h:120:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define INT_MAX __INT_MAX__
 ^
```

---

The same strategy also works well for finding struct definitions (very useful in case you have several architect specific header files and you are not sure which one is actually used!).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void FILE;

void f(void)
{
}
```

gives

```
main.c:3:14: error: conflicting types for ‘FILE’
 typedef void FILE;
              ^
In file included from main.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:48:25: note: previous declaration of ‘FILE’ was here
 typedef struct _IO_FILE FILE;
                         ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -E` will give us the output after preprocessor. But sometimes it will be difficult for a developer to verify if the `.c` file is very big and including some big header files. In such cases checking build output will be easier. `#warning` will print the message as warning during compilation.

```
#ifndef THE_FLAG
#warning "including ABC stuff"
// declare important stuff
#endif
```

We can make compiler warnings using `#pragma` also, but its not platform independent.

```
#pragma "including ABC stuff"
```

If we want to stop the compilation if some unwanted macros has been defined somewhere, we can use `#error`.

```
#ifdef UNWANTED_FLAG
#error "Build stopped. UNWANTED flag has been defined"
#endif
```

Comment: This will only tell you that the flag has been defined, but it won't tell you where it was defined.

Comment: @NathanFellman Everytime we may not need to find from where its defined. Most of the times we need to know whether its defined or not. I answed by considering this scenario also.

Comment: Your is a good answer to a different question.  It doesn't answer the OP's question.